# Excel VLOOKUP to compare 2 sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to use a VLOOKUP to compare 2 sheets of data. I need to see if there is missing data in one of the sheets.

the VLOOKUP I have so far is

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet1!$I$2:$I$2234,9,FALSE)),"MISSING FROM OTHER SHEET","")
```

But this just shows "MISSING FROM OTHER SHEET" for all rows, even though I have manually checked and can see some that are in both sheets.

Anybody any idea why this doesnt work?

B column contains a list of order numbers and the I column in sheet 1 contains a list of what appears to be the same order numbers. But with some discrepancies.

I am putting the formula into sheet 2, the column containing the order IDs in sheet 2 is "B", I am checking the data in sheet 1 to see if there are any missing orders in it and the column for order IDs in sheet 1 is "i"

I've checked some other answers here which is where I got my formula from but nothing really solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your table range `Sheet1!$I$2:$I$2234` is INCORRECT.

Change it to account for the complete table

For example

`Sheet1!$I$2:$Q$2234`

**EDIT**(Followup From Comments)

> and the column for order IDs in sheet 1 is "i"

In that case, keep the table range as it is and change `,9,` to `,1,`

Try

`=VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet1!$I$2:$I$2234,1,0)`

or

`=VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet1!I:I,1,0)`

Also ensure that the ID in Col B and the ID in Col I are same. If one of them has a space then Vlookup will fail. I have tested the above formula and it works.

Comment: What is your exact table range?

Comment: I am putting the formula into sheet 2, the column containing the order IDs is "B", I am checking the data in sheet 1 to see if there are any missing orders in it and the column for order IDs in sheet 1 is "i"

Comment: In that case simply replace `,9,` with `,1,`

Comment: The column number is always counted from the 1st column of the table and hence `1`

Comment: I have put 1 but there is no change

Comment: Try this `=VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet1!I:I,1,0)`

Comment: Even this works for me `=VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet1!$I$2:$I$2234,1,0)`

Comment: Sheet 2 contains rows of order information, Column B (2nd column) holds the order IDs, Sheet 1 also contains what looks like the same orders but there are discrepancies. The column holding the order IDs in sheet 1 is "i" this is the 9th column. and I need to check sheet 1 using the order IDs to find any missing orders

Comment: Trying all your suggestions again but get no change

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41188/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-kevlar)

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE), "Missing")
```

Put the above formula in Sheet1 A:A, Values to be looked up are in Sheet1 B:B, The range to look them up in is Sheet2 A:A. Manipulate the data like that and it will work.

Result:
It will return the value or it will say missing.